# php in-browser script cant restart/stop/start proccess

Tags: php, linux, permissions, systemctl

I have a simple script, which must restart the proccess on server:
`exec("systemctl stop listener.service");`
This script cannot be executed from browser and i don't know what's wrong with him.
Because if i run:
`exec("systemctl status listener.service | grep Active");`
it works!

I tried:

```
$command = "systemctl stop listener.service";
system($command);
shell_exec($command);
exec($command);

$command = "sudo systemctl stop listener.service";
system($command);
shell_exec($command);
exec($command);
```

I've added "%www-data   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" thought visudo. Browser shows 0 errors (error reporting is enabled, i tried to make mistakes especially - its shown in browser, but this script show 0 errors. I've closed all tags as its needed.

Nothing is works.

I even tried to run python script from php - it's still doesn't work.
If Im trying to run script from server console - it works, even if i dont giving root access to script. If Im trying to run script from server "php -a" console - it works, but it dont works from browser. Idk what is wrong with this script...

Comment: Does the userid used for the webserver have permission to use `sudo` without entering a password?

Comment: 1. what does your http error log say. 2. "run from the browser" I assume that you have put it in a .php file and hosted that on a webserver. - did you enclose your code  in `<?php ` and `?>`  tags? 3. did you add some `echo` statements to indicate that the code ran or just looked at the status of the service? 4. does the user hosting your http server have permission to run `sudo` without a password? or is your webserver hosted as root? Please [edit] your question and provide more information

Comment: I've added "%www-data   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" thought visudo. Browser shows 0 errors (error reporting is enabled, i tried to make mistakes - its shown in browser. I've closed all tags as its needed.

Comment: You need the `NOPASSWD` option to allow it to run `sudo` without entering a password. See https://documentation.arcserve.com/Arcserve-UDP/available/7.0/ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/UDPLUG/Content/AgentforLinuxUserGuide/udpl_conf_sudo_without_pswd.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i've to add directive using "sudo visudo":

```
%www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And now its working.
Thanks to @Barmar